# Why this for loop in shell doesn't work as expected?

Tags: shell, for-loop

I am a new shell learner, and I wrοte some for loops in shell.

```bash
i=(0.0001 0.00001 0.000001)
j=(0.5 0.6 0.7)

for i in "${i[@]}"
do
    for j in "${j[@]}"
    do
    echo "meta: $i, inner: $j"
    done
done
```

The output of the code is:

```bash
meta: 0.0001, inner: 0.5
meta: 0.0001, inner: 0.6
meta: 0.0001, inner: 0.7
meta: 0.00001, inner: 0.7
meta: 0.00001, inner: 0.6
meta: 0.00001, inner: 0.7
meta: 0.000001, inner: 0.7
meta: 0.000001, inner: 0.6
meta: 0.000001, inner: 0.7
```

But according to my point of view, the result should have been like this:

```bash
meta: 0.0001, inner: 0.5
meta: 0.0001, inner: 0.6
meta: 0.0001, inner: 0.7
meta: 0.00001, inner: 0.5
meta: 0.00001, inner: 0.6
meta: 0.00001, inner: 0.7
meta: 0.000001, inner: 0.5
meta: 0.000001, inner: 0.6
meta: 0.000001, inner: 0.7
```

I want to know why this happened?

After searching and trying, I know I need to do it like this to get the right result:

```bash
i_ls=(0.0001 0.00001 0.000001)
j_ls=(0.5 0.6 0.7)

for i in "${i_ls[@]}"
do
    for j in "${j_ls[@]}"
    do
    echo "meta: $i, inner: $j"
    done
done
```

It seems that the variable before and after `in` shouldn't be the same.

But I want to know what is the reason behind this different behaviour? Or how did shell compile the previous code to perform like that?

Comment: Which shell? Bash?

Comment: "It seems that the variable before and after in shouldn't be the same. But I want to know what is the reason behind this different behaviour": It's a variable: you can assign new values to it, and then the old value is lost. If you want to see what's going on, write some echo statements elsewhere, like `echo ${j[@]}` on every other line. If you want to understand why this happens, you may have to dig in to the source code of the shell.

Comment: General recommendation: don't do this: don't overwrite the variable you're looping over. It's bad behaviour, and in many languages, this will result in something unexpected. Possibly a crash, or worse, like incorrect results.

Comment: POSIX shell does not have arrays. If you need arrays, switch to zsh, ksh or bash.

Comment: Shell doesn't create a new scope for the loop. `i` is the array until you assign a new value *from* the array to it.

Answer (score 0):

`for var in "${arr[@]}"` assigns elements of  `arr` to `var`.

Accessing `j` when `j` is an array is equivalent to accessing `j[0]`.

So when `var` and `arr` are both `j`, the array element with index `0` is overwritten each time through the loop.

Consider:

```
declare -a i=(v0 v1 v2)
declare -p i
for i in "${i[@]}"; do declare -p i; done
```

```
declare -A a=(k1 v1 k2 v2)
declare -p a
for a in "${a[@]}"; do declare -p a; done
```

Comment: assigning array values to a variable that has not been declared as an array turns it into an indexed array (with elements of the same type): `unset i; declare -i i=10; declare -p i; i=(a b c); declare -p i; unset i; declare i=20; declare -p i; i=(a b c); declare -p i`